# git is not working well on VSCode remote container

Tags: git, docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose

In the host server, I have sources like this:

```
module
└── .git
└── sub_module
    └── some_files
    └── sub_sub_module 
        └── launch_server.py
```

Then I launch `docker-compose up` under `sub_module` dirs with volume settings as follows:

```
volumes:
  - .:/src
```

VSCode Remote Container is good in that it automatically volumes `~/.gitconfig`, but still working git on the launched container doesn't go well because there are no `.git` dirs on the container.

I tried to fix the volume as follows:

```
volumes:
  - .:/src
  - ../../.git:src/.git
```

but it doesn't go well because with this, the container-side git environment starts to see almost all things as changed files.

Is there any workaround for this? Thanks!

Comment: mount the container from module, then set the working dir / workspaceFolder to the module you want

Comment: Thanks @LawrenceCherone! Could you explain with some code or  more detailed procedure? I'm really interested your suggestion.